# Solve $\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = x$ for known $x$, unknown $\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

After looking at the list of trigonometric identities, I can't seem to find a way to solve this. Is it solvable?

$$\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = x.$$

What if I added another equation to the problem:

$$-\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = y,$$
where $\theta$ is the same and $y$ is also known?

Thanks.

EDIT:

OK, so using the linear combinations I was able to whip out:

$$a \sin(\theta) + b \cos(\theta) = x = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \sin(\theta + \phi),$$
where $\phi = \arcsin \left( \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ (as long as $a\geq 0$)

Giving me:

$$x = \sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}) \text{ and } \arcsin(x) - \frac{\pi}{4} = \theta.$$

All set! Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely solvable. You may have overlooked the identity though. Just look for identities that involve sums of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Hint: use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations

Comment: As you can solve the first equation, adding the second to the mix may well make it inconsistent.  The second is solvable alone, using a very similar technique.

Comment: Hmmm... $x$ is not the sine you write, there is is still a factor missing in your solution (equivalently, try $x=1$ and see what happens).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah you can write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigl[\cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta}\Bigl]$ as $\sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4}+\theta\Bigr)$ and solve for $x$.

Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and then try something.

Comment: I thought the identity was: $cos(\theta) = sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})$.

If I'm not mistaken, that would give me $sin(\theta) + sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}) = x$.

Comment: @Jcl: yeah sorry

Comment: @JCL: You could try this.

Comment: Both identities are true.  But the one Chandru1 suggested is more useful for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 8):

Another method goes by noting that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$. We have $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=x$, so $$\cos^2\theta+2\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sin^2\theta=x^2,$$ or $2\cos\theta\sin\theta=x^2-1$. But $2\cos\theta\sin\theta=\sin(2\theta)$, so $2\theta=\sin^{-1}(x^2-1)$, or $$ \theta=\frac12\sin^{-1}(x^2-1).$$

Comment: I think squaring introduces an extraneous solution $\pi + \theta$ (where $\theta$ is the correct solution) in this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Linear equations in $\sin \theta $ and $\cos \theta $ can be solved by a
resolvent quadratic equation, using the two identities (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/solve-trigonometric-equation-1-m-textcos-alpha-textsin-alpha/9185#9185)):

$$\cos \theta =\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2%
}}$$

and

$$\sin \theta =\frac{2\tan \frac{\theta }{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}}.$$

In this case, we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos \theta +\sin \theta  &=&x \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\left( 1-\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}\right) +2\tan \frac{%
\theta }{2}=x\left( 1+\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}\right)  \\
&\Leftrightarrow &(x+1)\tan ^{2}\frac{\theta }{2}-2\tan \frac{\theta }{2}%
+x-1=0 \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\tan \frac{\theta }{2}=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4-4(x+1)(x-1)}}{%
2(x+1)} \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\tan \frac{\theta }{2}=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{2-x^{2}}}{x+1} \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\theta =2\arctan \frac{1\pm \sqrt{2-x^{2}}}{x+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you know

$$ \cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta) = x $$

and

$$ -\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = y $$

then you have a system of two linear equations in the 'unknowns' $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, and thus can solve for the values of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$:

$$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{x+y}{2} $$
$$ \sin(\theta) = \frac{x-y}{2} $$

and then obtain $\theta$ in your favorite manner.

Comment: Wow.. I am ashamed of myself for even asking this question :)

Comment: Don't worry too much. While this is a neat trick and obvious in retrospect, there is something to be said about recognizing that you can solve for $\theta$ from just one equation. I've gotten a lot of good results over the years by recognizing I can use some method to solve a problem and then doing so, rather than spending more time looking for a 'simpler' solution that might not exist.