# Solve sum for theta

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any way to solve the following sum of trigonometric functions for theta without using a solver?
$$25\sin(\theta)-1.5\cos(\theta)=20$$

Comment: Relevant? [In the equation $x\cos(\theta) + y\sin(\theta) = z$ how do I solve in terms of $\theta$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33150/in-the-equation-x-cos-theta-y-sin-theta-z-how-do-i-solve-in-terms-of?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
25\sin\theta-1.5\cos\theta = \sqrt{25^2+1.5^2}\left( \frac{25}{\sqrt{25^2+1.5^2}}\sin\theta - \frac{1.5}{\sqrt{25^2+1.5^2}}\cos\theta  \right)
$$
$$
= \sqrt{25^2+1.5^2}(\cos\varphi\sin\theta-\sin\varphi\cos\theta) = \sqrt{25^2+1.5^2} \sin(\varphi-\theta).
$$
So you want
$$
\sin(\varphi-\theta)=\frac{20}{\sqrt{25^2+1.5^2}}.
$$
Take arcsines.

Comment: +1. I just fixed the plus in the first set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a numeric solution, define a function
$$
f\left(\theta\right) = 25 \sin \theta - 1.5 \cos \theta - 20 = 0
$$
and use a [root finding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Comment: I think OP was looking for a solution without using a solver

Comment: Eric, but the closed form is readily available. Besides, it shows the multitude of solutions. This answer might attract down-votes, I am afraid.

Comment: Then the OP should've asked for an analytic solution. To me, a "solver" is something like Mathematica. Besides, I qualified my answer with the phrase "if you're okay with a numeric solution." Finally, it's pretty clear that $f\left(\theta^*+2 \pi n\right) = 0$, where $\theta^*$ is a solution and $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $A\sin(t) + B\cos(t) = C$ is $t = 2\left(\pi n + \arctan{(\frac{A \pm \sqrt{A^2+B^2-C^2}}{B+C})}\right)$

Comment: Nice. But it'd be more helpful for OP if you show some derivation steps, or a name of a reference.