# Trigonometric equality: $\frac{1 + \sin A - \cos A}{1 + \sin A + \cos A} = \tan \frac{A}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can you guys give me a hint on how to proceed with proving this trigonometric equality? I have a feeling I need to use the half angle identity for $\tan \frac{\theta}{2}$. The stuff I have tried so far(multiplying numerator and denominator by $1 + \sin A - \cos A$) has lead to a dead end.

> Prove that,
>   $$
> \dfrac{1 + \sin A - \cos A}{1 + \sin A + \cos A} = \tan \dfrac{A}{2}
> $$

Comment: The fact that you need to use half angle (or equivalently double angle) identities is built into the shape of the problem. The simple formulas express $\sin(2x)$, $\cos(2x)$, $\tan(2x)$ in terms of trigonometric functions of $x$, so the *mechanical* way to proceed is to let $x=A/2$. Then $A=2x$. Now work on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\textbf{Method 1.}$ You have

\begin{align*}
\frac{1+ \sin{A} - \cos{A}}{1+\sin{A} + \cos{A}} &= \frac{ \cos^{2}\frac{A}{2} + \sin^{2}\frac{A}{2} + 2\cdot \sin\frac{A}{2}\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2} - \Bigl(\cos^{2}\frac{A}{2} - \sin^{2}\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)}{\cos^{2}\frac{A}{2} + \sin^{2}\frac{A}{2} + 2\cdot \sin\frac{A}{2}\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2} + \Bigl(\cos^{2}\frac{A}{2} -\sin^{2}\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)} \\ &=\frac{ \Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)^{2} - \Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr) \cdot \Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2} - \sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)}{\Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)^{2} + \Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr) \cdot \Bigl(\cos\frac{A}{2} - \sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr)} \\ &= \frac{ \cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2} - \cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2}}{\cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2} + \cos\frac{A}{2} -\sin\frac{A}{2}} \qquad \Bigl[ \text{cancelling}\ \Bigl(\small\cos\frac{A}{2} +\sin\frac{A}{2}\Bigr) \ \Bigr] \\ &= \tan\frac{A}{2}
\end{align*}

$\textbf{Method 2.}$ Here is another way of seeing this. By using something called Componendo and Dividendo.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo

Let $$\frac{1+\sin{A} -\cos{A}}{1+\sin{A} + \cos{A}} = \frac{k}{1}$$ Now applying componendo and dividendo we get $$\frac{1+ \sin{A}}{-\cos{A}} = \frac{k+1}{k-1} \Longrightarrow \frac{\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}}{-\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}} = \frac{k+1}{k-1} \qquad (1)$$

Again using componendo dividendo on $(1)$ we get $$\frac{\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2} -\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}}{\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2} +\cos\frac{A}{2}-\sin\frac{A}{2}} = \frac{k+1 +k-1}{k+1-k+1} \Longrightarrow k=\frac{\sin\frac{A}{2}}{\cos\frac{A}{2}}=\tan\frac{A}{2}$$

$\textbf{Method 3.}$ Another way of looking into this would be,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+\sin{A}-\cos{A}}{1+\sin{A}+\cos{A}} =\frac{(1-\cos{A})+\sin{A}}{(1+\cos{A}) + \sin{A}} &= \frac{ 2\:\sin^{2}\frac{A}{2} + 2\cdot\sin\frac{A}{2}\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2}}{2\:\cos^{2}\frac{A}{2} + 2 \cdot\sin\frac{A}{2}\cdot \cos\frac{A}{2}} \\ &= \frac{2\:\sin\frac{A}{2}}{2\:\cos\frac{A}{2}} \cdot \Biggl(\frac{\cos\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{A}{2}}{\cos\frac{A}{2} + \sin\frac{A}{2}}\Biggr) \\ &= \tan\frac{A}{2}
\end{align*}

$\textbf{Method 4.}$ My younger brother mentioned about this method. Multiplying numerator and deominator by $(1+\sin{A}-\cos{A})$ we get 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1+\sin{A}-\cos{A}}{1+\sin{A}+\cos{A}} \times \frac{1+\sin{A}-\cos{A}}{1+\sin{A}-\cos{A}} &= \frac{(1+\sin{A}-\cos{A})^{2}}{(1+\sin{A})^{2}-\cos^{2}{A}} \\ &= \frac{2 + 2\: \sin{A} -2\cdot\sin{A}\cdot \cos{A} -2\cos{A}}{2\: \sin{A} + 2\sin^{2}{A}} \\ &= \frac{(2-2\cos{A}) \cdot (1+\sin{A})}{2\:\sin{A} \cdot (1+\sin{A})} \\  &=\frac{1-\cos{A}}{\sin{A}} = \frac{2\: \sin^{2}\frac{A}{2}}{2\cdot \sin\frac{A}{2} \cdot \cos\frac{A}{2}} \\ &=\tan\frac{A}{2}
\end{align*}

Oh once again when I looked at the question I realize that you attempted this method. Hopefully now it's clear.

Comment: Ah, the old $1=\cos^2(A/2)+\sin^2(A/2)$ trick.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, may be not too old for me :)

Comment: Nice! I ended up with something similar to your first example. Also Thanks for the componendo and dividendo solution!

Comment: Who is this "younger brother" about whom you speak ?!?! (+1)

Comment: I had mixed things up when opening the square. Thanks for clarifying this, @Chandru.

Comment: @mathguy80: Welcome.

Answer (score 18):

Now that OP has understood how to prove this, here is a geometric proof for certain angles, just for fun :-)

Consider the figure:

[image]

$\displaystyle \triangle ABC$ is a right angled triangle with the right angle being at $\displaystyle C$.

$\displaystyle \angle{CAB} = A$ and $\displaystyle AB = 1$ and thus $\displaystyle BC = \sin A$ and $\displaystyle AC = \cos A$.

Now $\displaystyle AO$ is the angular bisector of $\displaystyle \angle{CAB}$. We select $\displaystyle O$ so that $\displaystyle O$ is the in-center (point of intersection of angular bisectors of a triangle). Let the in-radius $\displaystyle OD$ be $\displaystyle r$.

Now $\displaystyle BE = BF$ and $\displaystyle AE = AD$ and adding gives us $\displaystyle BF + AD = AB = 1$

Now $\displaystyle BF = BC - FC =BC - OD$ (as $\displaystyle ODCF$ is a square).

Thus $\displaystyle BF = \sin A - r$. Similarly $\displaystyle AD = \cos A - r$.

Thus $\displaystyle \sin A + \cos A - 2r = 1$.

Using $\displaystyle \triangle ADO$, $\displaystyle \tan \frac{A}{2} = \frac{OD}{AD} = \frac{r}{\cos A - r}$

Since $\displaystyle 2r = \sin A + \cos A -1 $ we get

$$\tan \frac{A}{2} = \frac{2r}{2\cos A - 2r} = \frac{\sin A + \cos A - 1}{\cos A - \sin A + 1}$$

It is easy to verify that

$$ \frac{\sin A + \cos A - 1}{\cos A - \sin A + 1} = \frac{\sin A - \cos A + 1}{\cos A + \sin A + 1}$$

Incidently, the fact that in a right triangle (hypotenuse $c$), the in-radius is given by $ a + b -c = 2r$ and also by $r = \frac{\triangle}{s}$ ($\triangle$ is the area, $s$ is the semi-perimeter) can be used to prove the pythagoras theorem ($a^2 + b^2 = c^2$)!

Comment: Awesome, how did u think of constructing such a triangle.

Comment: Great Yaar... simply superb

Comment: If I could upvote this a dozen times, I would.  Gorgeous!

Comment: Wow!, This was a somewhat difficult proof for me, you've proved it geometrically!

Answer (score 7):

An alternative solution:

Substituting

$$\tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\frac{\sin(A)}{1+\cos(A)}$$

and multiplying through to clear the fractions quickly reduces the statement to one which is trivially true. Then working backwards through the simplifications you have made gives the proof.

**Edit (providing requested clarification):**

When you make the above substitution, you have

$$\frac{1+\sin A - \cos A}{1+\sin A + \cos A} = \frac{\sin A }{1+\cos A}$$

So

$$ (1+\sin A - \cos A)(1+\cos A) = \sin A (1+\sin A + \cos A)$$

And cancelling terms gives

$$1-\cos^2 A = \sin^2 A$$

So, using that as the starting point for your proof, "uncancelling" terms, and dividing gives the required identity.

Comment: That's good, and it supports mathguy's feeling that the half-angle identity for tangent would be useful. My solution is for those of us who have forgotten that half-angle identity.

Comment: I tried that but ended up going in circles, ending up with the other identity $\frac{1 - \cos A}{\sin A}$ Can you clarify what you mean by clearing fractions?

Comment: Amazingly, a Canadian province I shall not name had for a long time the following final exam grading policy. In proving a trigonometric identity, a student could not "mix" the sides.  Any computation step had to deal with one side or the other!

Answer (score 7):

There is a theorem$^1$ that is worth knowing (I used it in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/solve-trigonometric-equation-1-m-textcos-alpha-textsin-alpha/9185#9185) answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/solve-trigonometric-equation-1-m-textcos-alpha-textsin-alpha) question) that states:

*All direct trigonometric functions of $A$ ($2\alpha$) can be expressed rationally in terms of the tangent of $\frac{A}{2}$ ($\alpha$).*

Combining $\sin A=2\sin \frac{A}{2}\cdot \cos \frac{A}{2}$ and $\cos ^{2}
\frac{A}{2}+\sin ^{2}\frac{A}{2}=1$, we get (for $\cos \frac{A}{2}\neq 0$)

$$\sin A=\frac{2\sin \frac{A}{2}\cdot \cos \frac{A}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{A}{2}
+\sin ^{2}\frac{A}{2}}=\frac{2\tan \frac{A}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{A}{2}};
\qquad (1)$$

and from $\cos A=\cos ^{2}\frac{A}{2}-\sin ^{2}\frac{A}{2}$, for $\cos \frac{A}{2}\neq 0$,

$$\cos A=\frac{\cos ^{2}\frac{A}{2}-\sin ^{2}\frac{A}{2}}{\cos ^{2}\frac{A}{2}
+\sin ^{2}\frac{A}{2}}=\frac{1-\tan ^{2}\frac{A}{2}}{1+\tan ^{2}\frac{A}{2}}.
\qquad (2)$$

To prove the identity multiply the LHS numerator and denominator by $1+\tan
^{2}\frac{A}{2}$ and use $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1+\sin A-\cos A}{1+\sin A+\cos A} &=&\frac{1+2\tan \frac{A}{2}-1+\tan
^{2}\frac{A}{2}}{1+2\tan \frac{A}{2}+1+\tan ^{2}\frac{A}{2}} \\
&=&\frac{2\tan ^{2}\frac{A}{2}+2\tan \frac{A}{2}}{2+2\tan \frac{A}{2}}=\tan 
\frac{A}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

--

$^1$ J. Calado, *Compêndio de Trigonometria*, 1967.

Comment: This question has got some excellent answers. This identity is new to me, I'm sure it will come in handy! Thank you!

Comment: @mathguy80: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

First write $A=2b$. Then make appropriate use of $\tan b=\sin b/\cos b$, $\sin2b=2\sin b\cos b$, and $\cos2b=2\cos^2b-1=1-2\sin^2b$.

Comment: Thanks. That's a neat substitution. It's a simple double angle identity from there. This also lead me backwards to, $\sin x = 2\sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}$ and $\cos x = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

The following is a method that in general I would **not** advocate as an approach to proving the usual trigonometric identities by hand.  However, the idea has nice connections with other parts of mathematics, so it is worth mentioning.

There is a standard *rational parametrization* of (most of) the unit circle.  Let $t=\tan(\theta/2)$.  Then 
$$\cos \theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$
This parametrization gives a general method for integrating rational functions of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$.  Parametrizations of the same general character are useful in number theory and elsewhere.

In our problem, the left-hand side is
$$  \frac{1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}{1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}.$$
Bring top and bottom to the common denominator $1+t^2$. Things collapse, we get $t$.  (As in the trigonometric proofs, we close our eyes to division by $0$.)

Comment: Another excellent answer. I had seen this substitution approach in some examples, but was unaware of what it was called. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done (mechanically) with complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the identities$$1+\cos A=2 \cos ^{2} \frac{A}{2}, 1-\sin A=2 \sin ^{2} \frac{1}{2} , \sin A=2 \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cos\frac{\theta}{2},
$$
We have $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1+\sin A-\cos A}{1+\sin A+\cos A} &=\frac{2 \sin ^{2} \frac{A}{2}+2 \sin \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{A}{2}}{2 \cos ^{2} \frac{A}{2}+2 \sin \frac{A}{2} \cos \frac{A}{2}} \\
&=\frac{\sin \frac{A}{2}\left(\sin \frac{A}{2}+\cos \frac{A}{2}\right)}{\cot \frac{A}{2}\left(\cos \frac{A}{2}+\sin \frac{A}{2}\right)} \\
&=\tan \frac{A}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$