# Integral related to Arcsinh(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

It is not difficult to verify that
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left[ \log\Big(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\Big) \right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$
for $x\geq 0$, say.

How would one calculate the indefinite integral 
$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \ \!\mathrm dx$$
without knowing this? I have tried many of the usual tricks, without success.

The title of the question is chosen because Mathematica outputs $\text{Arcsinh}(x)+C$ as the answer.

Comment: You may use [Integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)

Comment: Of course $\operatorname{arcsinh} x  = \log{(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}$.  This is done by writing $sinh$ in terms of exponentials, then solving a quadratic equation to obtain the inverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a substitution for $x=\tan\theta$ and $\mathrm dx=\sec^2\theta\,\mathrm d\theta$ to get

$$
\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}\,\mathrm d\theta.
$$

Then use that $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$ to get the integral

$$
\int\sec\theta\,\mathrm d\theta.
$$

EDIT: In response to the comment by Sasha:  This is one of the standard integrals in a calculus class.  I usually just derive it in class and have students memorize it along with the other trigonometric functions.  Just multiply top and bottom by $\sec\theta + \tan\theta$ to get

$$
\int \frac{\sec^2\theta + \tan\theta\sec\theta}{\sec\theta+\tan\theta}\mathrm d\theta.
$$

Then $u=\sec\theta + \tan\theta$, $\mathrm du=\sec\theta\tan\theta + \sec^2\theta\;\mathrm d\theta.$  The answer is then $\ln|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+C$.  Putting this in terms of $x$ one gets $\ln|\sqrt{1+x^2}+x|+C$.

Comment: Why is the integral $\int \sec \theta \mathrm{d} \theta$ any easier ?

Comment: You could also finish it off with one of the answers from [Ways to evaluate $\int \sec \theta \mathrm{d} \theta$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-d-theta).

Comment: @Mike Spivey: What a neat link.

Answer (score 8):

One would use [Euler's substitution](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Euler_substitutions). Also on [PlanetMath](https://planetmath.org/EulersSubstitutionsForIntegration).

Alternatively, one could use $x = \sinh(t)$, because $1+x^2 = 1+\sinh^2(t) = \cosh^2(t)$, and
because $\mathrm{d}x = \sinh^\prime(t) \mathrm{d}t = \cosh(t) \mathrm{d}t$. Therefore, using that $\cosh(t) >0 $ for real $t$:

$$
  \int \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \int \frac{\cosh(t)}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(t)}} \mathrm{d} t = \int \mathrm{d} t = t + C
$$
Substituting back $\int \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \operatorname{arcsinh}(x) + C$

Comment: Your answer gives arcsinh($x$), not the function involving the logarithm. I guess after you'd have to further solve $e^z-e^{-z} = 2w$ which ends up being a quadratic in $e^z$ to get the answer I want.

Comment: @Jum The answer you want is provided by Euler's substitution. I was explaining how _Mathematica_ arrived at arcsine hyperbolic.