# Evaluating $\int\sec x \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\sec x \,\mathrm dx = \ln\left|\sec{x} + \tan{x}\right|+ C = \ln{\left|\tan\left(\frac{x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right|} + C$$

My question is how? How are these derived?

Comment: For the first, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-mathrm-d-theta).

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Primitive_of_Secant_Function has two proofs of the former, though the proof of the corollary is absent

Comment: See [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that

$$
\int \csc x dx = \ln \tan \frac x 2.
$$
Shifting the integration variable by $\pi/2$ gives, using the fact that $\sin(x+\pi/2) = \cos x$,

$$
\int \sec x  dx= \ln \tan \left({\frac x 2 + \frac \pi 4 }\right).
$$

To prove the first integral, write
$$
\csc x = \frac{1}{2 \sin(x/2) \cos(x/2) } = \frac 1 2 \left[\cot \frac x 2 + \tan \frac x 2 \right].
$$

Comment: Thank you :) Its helping..

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite your integrand in the form
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)^2}\,.$$
Setting $t=\sin(x)$ gives us
$$\int\frac{1}{1-t^2}dt\,.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

For most people, they were derived by someone else, or a textbook, telling them.
To check that they work, differentiate them.
$$\frac d{dx}\ln(\sec x+\tan x)=\frac{\sec x\tan x+\sec^2x}{\sec x+\tan x}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer:)