# Find integral $\int\frac{1}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Need help with this integral $$\int\frac{1}{\cos x}dx$$ I know that the answer is $$\ln|\operatorname{tg} x+\sec x|$$ I tried transforming 1 into $\cos^2x + \sin^2x$ but it led to nothing. Need to solve it using simplest way without new variables and differential transformations.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-mathrm-d-theta).

Comment: The goal of an indefinite integral is only to find the antiderivative. If you already know the antiderivative, try taking its derivative, and see how that simplifies down to $1/\cos(x)$. For simplicity, do this without the absolute value - usually that is found by doing a case analysis (or a substitution the leads to $\int 1/u\,du$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my way of finding this integral:
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{\cos{x}}dx =\int \frac{\cos{x}}{\cos^2{x}} dx= \int \frac{\cos{x}}{1-\sin^2{x}} dx\\ \text{substitution }  \Big|\begin{array}{cc}\sin{x}=u \\ \cos{x}dx=du\end{array} \Big| \\= \int \frac{1}{1-u^2}du  = \tanh^{-1}u +C= \tanh^{-1}(\sin{x})+C\end{align}.$$

Comment: Liked this, thx)

Answer (score 0):

1/COSX=secx, multiply and divide it by secx+tanx you get
int(secx^2+secxtanx)/(secx+tanx) dx which gives 
=log(tanx+secx)

[image]

Comment: Please format your answer using MathJax, a LaTeX-style system for typesetting math in answers.

Comment: Consider writing your answer with mathjax. A small guide about it can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \tan x= \sec^2 x
$$
and
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \sec x= \sec x \tan x
$$
so that:
$$
d(\tan x +\sec x)= \dfrac{\tan x +\sec x}{\cos x} dx
$$
and:
$$
\dfrac{d(\tan x +\sec x)}{\tan x +\sec x}=\dfrac{dx}{\cos x}
$$
so, integrating you have the result.

Comment: Thx, it was very helpful!