# Definite integral of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I've got problems with this integral:

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

First I substitute $x=2\arctan(x)$ but this leads nowhere. Any hints for solving?

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ since $\cos x>0$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6695/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By just substituting $x=\arctan t$, from $\cos^2(\arctan t)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ it follows that:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\text{arcsinh}(1)=\color{red}{\log(1+\sqrt{2}).}$$

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and $\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)$. Then partial fractions will be useful.

In other words, try $u=\sin(x)$, then $\cos^2(x)=1-u^2$ and $\frac1{\cos(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=1$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\frac1{\cos^2(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\frac1{1-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I didn't vote down your hint. 

What do you mean with $d \sin(x)$?

Comment: $\mathrm{d}\sin(x)=\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ or substitute $u=\sin(x)$ to get $\int\frac1{\cos(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x= \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$

Comment: Why the new downvote?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: @jacmeird: there have been two downvotes (one was taken back). I was just wondering what some people have found problematic about this answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{\dfrac1{\cos^2x}}=|\sec x|$$

In $\in[0,\pi/4],\sec x>0\implies|\sec x|=+\sec x$

Now use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy trick for this integral:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\cos x}=\int\frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x}dx=\int\frac{d\sin x}{1-\sin^2x}$$ and $$\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}=\text{artanh(u)}=\text{artanh}(\sin x).$$

Comment: A cute approach!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Note that
>   $\ds{\totald{\bracks{\sec\pars{x} + \tan\pars{x}}}{x} =
> \sec\pars{x}\tan\pars{x} + \sec^{2}\pars{x}}$ such that:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\root{1 \over \cos^{2}\pars{x}}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sec\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}
{\sec^{2}\pars{x} + \sec\pars{x}\tan\pars{x} \over \sec\pars{x} + \tan\pars{x}}
\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
\ln\pars{\vphantom{\large A}\sec\pars{x} + \tan\pars{x}}
\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ \pi/4} =
\ln\pars{\sec\pars{\pi/4} + \tan\pars{\pi/4} \over \sec\pars{0} + \tan\pars{0}}
\\[3mm] & =
\color{#f00}{\ln\pars{\root{2} + 1}} \approx 0.8814
\end{align}