# How can I solve $\int \sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, substitution

$$\int \sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx$$

I've tried some step-by-step calculators, but what they give is way beyond my level. Is there any "simple" way to solve this?

Comment: Integration by parts, the substitution $x=\sinh t$ (or $x=\tan\theta$) or both are the usual ways. And they *are* simple ways: please show your efforts to let us understand your troubles.

Answer (score 3):

Several people have pointed out that you can write $x=\tan\theta.$ That gets you $dx=\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sec\theta,$ so you have
$$
\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta.
$$
This is one of the standard examples of a standard trick:
\begin{align}
\int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta & = \int(\sec\theta) \Big(\sec^2\theta\,d\theta\Big) = \overbrace{\int u\,dv = uv -\int v\,du}^{\Large\text{integration by parts}} \\[10pt]
& = \sec\theta\tan\theta - \int \tan^2\theta\sec\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
& = \sec\theta\tan\theta - \int(\sec^2\theta-1)\sec\theta\,d\theta \\[10pt]
& = \sec\theta\tan\theta - \int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta + \int\sec\theta\,d\theta. \\[15pt]
\text{Thus we have } & \int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta = \Big(\text{something}\Big) - \int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta. \\[10pt]
\text{Adding the integral to } \\
\qquad \text{both sides, we get } & 2\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta = \Big(\text{something}\Big). \\[10pt]
\text{And so } & \phantom{2}\int\sec^3\theta\,d\theta = \frac 1 2 \Big(\text{something}\Big) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \left( \sec\theta\tan\theta + \int \sec\theta\,d\theta\right).
\end{align}
Then you have the problem of finding that last integral, which is somewhat challenging as well.

Comment: To evaluate that last integral: [Integration of secant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340800/integration-of-secant)

Comment: @Michael Hardy I think $\sqrt{1+x^2}\neq\sec\theta$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg : Did you have in mind $\sqrt{1+x^2} = \left|\sec\theta\right|\text{?}$ I'd probably just look separately at intervals where the secant is negative.

Comment: OK! I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
try substitute 
$$x=\tan { \theta  } $$

Answer (score 2):

$x=\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$  also helps.

Comment: ...which is just another way to write $\sinh(t)$, though I do give you credit for that since given that the OP did not understand the solution given by the step-by-step calculators, he/she may not have heard of hyperbolic trig functions.

Comment: @projectilemotion I think this way more easier than a way with $x=\tan{t}$ because there we get $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2t}}=\frac{1}{|\cos{t}|}$, which is not so easy.

Comment: the OP has indeed not heard/learned of hyperbolic trig functions; I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @username_DNE You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is just straight up trigonometric substitution with $x=\tan(\theta)$ and $dx=\sec^{2}(\theta)\:d\theta$. Then use the identity $1+\tan^{2}(\theta)=\sec^{2}(\theta)$ to eliminate the square root and integrate from there.

Comment: By your way there is a problem with a square root. See please my previous comment.

Comment: The integrand just works out to be $\sec^{3}(\theta)$...