# Deriving $\sec x$ integral in a weird, wrong way. I can't find where I am wrong.

Tags: calculus, integration

\begin{align*}
\int \sec x dx & = \int {{\cos^2x} \over {\cos^3x}}dx
\\&= \int \sec^3x \cos^2x   dx =\int  \sec^3x (1-\sin^2x) dx
\\&=\int \sec^2x  \sec x   dx -\int \tan^2x \sec x  dx
\\&=\tan x  \sec x + \int \tan^2x \sec  x  dx -\int \tan^2x  \sec  x  dx
\\&=\tan x \sec  x.
\end{align*}
I kind of messed it up. I know how to derive the $\int \sec  x  dx$ with alternative way so I can find out it is wrong but can't find out why.

Will be very appreciated with your help.

Comment: Just find out about my mistake. I was wrong about the differentiation of sec x...

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int \sec x dx & = \int {{\cos^2x} \over {\cos^3x}}dx
\\&= \int \sec^3x \cos^2x   dx =\int  \sec^3x (1-\sin^2x) dx
\\&=\int \sec^2x  \sec x   dx -\int \tan^2x \sec x  dx
\\&=[\tan x  \sec x - \int \tan^2x \sec  x  dx] -\int \tan^2x  \sec  x  dx
\\-\int \sec x dx &= \tan x  \sec x  -2\int \sec^3x  dx
\end{align*}
but to calculate $\int \sec^3x$ you must know what is the $\int \sec x dx$
\begin{align*}
\\-\int \sec x dx &= \tan x  \sec x  - (\tan x  \sec x + \int \sec x dx)
\\&=-\ln|\sec x +\tan x|
\\\int \sec x dx &= \ln|\sec x +\tan x|.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\sec x\,dx=\int\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2x}dx=\text{artanh}(\sin x)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a sign error when you integrated by parts.  You correctly obtained
\begin{align*}
\int \sec x~dx & = \int \frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^3x}~dx\\
               & = \int \sec^3x\cos^2x~dx\\
               & = \int \sec^3x(1 - \sin^2x)~dx\\
               & = \int \sec^3x~dx - \int \sec^3x\sin^2x~dx\\
               & = \int \sec^2x\sec x~dx - \int \tan^2x\sec x~dx
\end{align*}
To do the first integral, we integrate by parts.  Setting $u = \sec x$ and $dv = \sec^2x~dx$ yields
\begin{align*}
u & = \sec x & dv & = \sec^2x~dx\\
du & = \sec x\tan x & v & = \tan x
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$\int \sec^2x\sec x~dx = uv - \int v~du = \sec x\tan x - \int \tan^2x\sec x~dx$$
so you should have obtained
$$\int \sec x~dx = \sec x\tan x - 2\int \tan^2x\sec x~dx$$

The answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/ways-to-evaluate-int-sec-theta-mathrm-d-theta) describe many clever ways of evaluating the integral
$$\int \sec x~dx$$